# Weird things with C# events

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm learning events and delegates and decided to write such console application. 
Program should message me every 3 and 5 seconds. But it doesn't do anything.

I have a class `WorkingTimer`:

```
class WorkingTimer
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private long _working_seconds = 0;

    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public event MyDelegate Every3Seconds;
    public event MyDelegate Every5Seconds;

    public WorkingTimer()
    {
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;            
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        _working_seconds++;
        if (Every3Seconds != null && _working_seconds % 3 == 0)
            Every3Seconds();
        if (Every5Seconds != null && _working_seconds % 5 == 0)
            Every5Seconds();
    }
}
```

and actually the program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorkingTimer wt = new WorkingTimer();
        wt.Every3Seconds += wt_Every3Seconds;
        wt.Every5Seconds += wt_Every5Seconds;
    }

    static void wt_Every3Seconds()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3 seconds elapsed");
    }

    static void wt_Every5Seconds()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("5 seconds elapsed");
    }
}
```

So, when I run it doesn't do anything. But I tried to make exactly same program in Windows Form Application and it worked great. The difference only is in Timer events Elapsed and Tick.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the program is closed at the end of the `Main` function... Did you try adding a dummy `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of `Main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program exits at the end of the `Main` function. Try adding a dummy `Console.ReadLine()` to keep it running.

The resulting code would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WorkingTimer wt = new WorkingTimer();
    wt.Every3Seconds += wt_Every3Seconds;
    wt.Every5Seconds += wt_Every5Seconds;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```